# How to customize s:formattedText

Tags: css, seam, richfaces

I am using `<s:formattedText>` for formatting my page.It works fine as expected, but the padding around the text seams to be large. So I applied my own styleClass to this element but it didn't take effect. Firebug shows that the paragraph has styleClass 'seamTextPara'.

Where will I be able to find details on the above styleClass and how to customize it?

Answer (score 1):

```
p.seamTextPara
{
  display: inline;
}
```